# VBA color entire row base on Cell text

Tags: excel, vba, colors, conditional-statements

example row B4 to AN4 to color green base on cell AF4 is ready as green , and in progress as yellow, and pending as red.
this applied for all rows

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: i tried from someone  suggestion .....      but this only color the particular cell                                                                         
      Sub ColourChange()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("a2:az500")
        If cell.Value = "Available" Then
            cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGreen
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Deal" Then
            cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Sold +Excl" Then
           End If
    Next
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight specific columns of rows based on the given criteria

```
Sub ColourChange()

    Dim MySht As Worksheet
    Dim MyRng As Range
    Set MySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set MyRng = MySht.UsedRange.Columns("AF")
    
    For Each cell In MyRng.Cells
        Set activeRow = Range("B:AN").Rows(cell.Row)
        Select Case cell.Value    '// you can add the filter here
            Case "Available", "Resell"
                activeRow.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGreen
            Case "Deal", "Sold +Excl", "Sold Excl", "Holdback", _
                 "Pending", "Expired", "Sold CoX"
                activeRow.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
            Case "Sold nonX", "Sold NonX"
                activeRow.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbBlue
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested but something along these lines should work:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim rw As Range, clr As Long
    Set rw = ActiveSheet.Range("B4:AN4") 'start row
    
    Do While Application.CountA(rw) > 0 'loop while there's data
        Select Case rw.EntireRow.Columns("AF").Value
            Case "ready": clr = vbGreen
            Case "in progress": clr = vbYellow
            Case "pending": clr = vbRed
            Case Else: clr = -1
        End Select
        
        If clr <> -1 Then
            rw.Interior.Color = clr         'apply fill
        Else
            rw.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'no fill
        End If
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0) 'next row
    Loop
End Sub
```